# Generate dynamic PATINDEX statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two strings:

```
DECLARE @Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John A Mak|Street Road UAE'
DECLARE @Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]|[Address1],[Address2]'
```

Note: Both strings are dynamic may comes with more or less values.

Expected result: Want to if any of the given text present in the given columns using the `PATINDEX`. The following `PATINDEX` statement gonna used in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement.

```
PATINDEX('John',[First Name]) + PATINDEX('A',[First Name]) + PATINDEX('Mak',[First Name]) + 
PATINDEX('John',[Last Name]) + PATINDEX('A',[Last Name]) + PATINDEX('Mak',[Last Name]) +
PATINDEX('John',[Middle Name]) + PATINDEX('A',[Middle Name]) + PATINDEX('Mak',[Middle Name]) +
PATINDEX('Street',[Address1]) + PATINDEX('Road',[Address1]) + PATINDEX('UAE',[Address1]) +
PATINDEX('Street',[Address2]) + PATINDEX('Road',[Address2]) + PATINDEX('UAE',[Address2]) > 0
```

My try:

```
DECLARE @Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John A Mak|Street Road UAE'
DECLARE @Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]|[Address1],[Address2]'
DECLARE @Length int = 0
DECLARE @Length1 int = 0
DECLARE @Length2 int = 0
DECLARE @Position int = 0
DECLARE @Position1 int = 0
DECLARE @Position2 int = 0
DECLARE @Value varchar(max)
DECLARE @Value1 varchar(max)
DECLARE @Value2 varchar(max)
DECLARE @P_Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @P_Str3 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @P_Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @FinalString VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @P_Str1 = @Str1+'|';
SET @P_Str3 = @Str2+'|';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempt', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempt;
CREATE TABLE #tempt(keywords varchar(max));


WHILE CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str3, @Position2+1)>0
BEGIN
    set @Length2 = CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str3, @Position2+1) - @Position2
    set @Value2 = SUBSTRING(@P_Str3, @Position2, @Length2)

    SET @P_Str2 = @Value2+',';

    PRINT('--'+@P_Str2);
    --WHILE LOOP for creating string for PAT INDEX
    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @P_Str2, @Position+1)>0 
    BEGIN
        set @Length = CHARINDEX(',', @P_Str2, @Position+1) - @Position
        set @Value = SUBSTRING(@P_Str2, @Position, @Length)

        WHILE CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str1, @Position1+1)>0
        BEGIN
            set @Length1 = CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str1, @Position1+1) - @Position1
            set @Value1 = SUBSTRING(@P_Str1, @Position1, @Length1)  

            PRINT('Value1--'+@Value1);
            PRINT('Value--'+@Value);
            INSERT INTO #tempt 
                SELECT DISTINCT split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Keywords
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT CAST ('<S>' + REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(@Value1)), ' ', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS Element 
                ) AS a
                CROSS APPLY Element.nodes ('/S') AS split(a)
                WHERE split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') <> ''; 

                SET @FinalString  += STUFF(( SELECT '(PATINDEX('''+keywords+''','+@Value+'),''''0'''') + '
                                             FROM #tempt FOR XML PATH('')), 1,0, '');   

                DELETE FROM #tempt;

            SET @Position1 = CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str1, @Position1+@Length1) +1
        END

        SET @Position = CHARINDEX(',', @P_Str2, @Position+@Length) +1

    END 

    SET @Position2 = CHARINDEX('|', @P_Str3, @Position2+@Length2) +1

END 
PRINT(@FinalString);
```

But unable to get the expected result.

Comment: Your expected result is not clear to me. could please edit your question

Comment: @Sami, Edited. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not pretty dynamic SQL, however...

```
USE Sandbox;
DECLARE @Str1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John A Mak|Street Road UAE';
DECLARE @Str2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]|[Address1],[Address2]';

DECLARE @WHERE nvarchar(MAX);
SET @WHERE = STUFF((SELECT N' + ' + NCHAR(10) + 
                         STUFF((SELECT N' + ' +NCHAR(10)+
                                       N'PATINDEX(' + QUOTENAME(DSn.Item,'''') + N',' + DSc.Item + N')' --This trusts no injection.I don't like this.
                                FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(DS1.Item,' ') DSn
                                     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(DS2.Item,',') DSc
                                ORDER BY DSc.ItemNumber, DSn.ItemNumber
                                FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,4,N'')
                  FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (@Str1,'|') DS1
                       CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (@Str2,'|') DS2
                  WHERE DS1.ItemNumber = DS2.ItemNumber
                  ORDER BY DS1.ItemNumber
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,4,N'') + N' > 0'

SELECT @WHERE;
```

This outputs:

```
PATINDEX('John',[First Name]) + 
PATINDEX('A',[First Name]) + 
PATINDEX('Mak',[First Name]) + 
PATINDEX('John',[Last Name]) + 
PATINDEX('A',[Last Name]) + 
PATINDEX('Mak',[Last Name]) + 
PATINDEX('John',[Middle Name]) + 
PATINDEX('A',[Middle Name]) + 
PATINDEX('Mak',[Middle Name]) + 
PATINDEX('Street',[Address1]) + 
PATINDEX('Road',[Address1]) + 
PATINDEX('UAE',[Address1]) + 
PATINDEX('Street',[Address2]) + 
PATINDEX('Road',[Address2]) + 
PATINDEX('UAE',[Address2]) > 0
```

Note the use of [`DelimitedSplit8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), which you'll need on your instance to get this done.

*Edit/Note: This is not injection safe. Specifically because of `+ DSc.Item +`. The OP, in their sample data, provides already quoted strings; it is therefore **assumed** that the strings are **properly** quoted; I.e. **not** `"[" & ColumnName & "]"` (that is still open to injection, as any `]` passed won't be escaped). If the columnnames are not properly quoted elsewhere, I strongly suggest removing the brackets (`[]`) in the passed value and using `+ QUOTENAME(DSc.Item) +` instead.*

Comment: Previous comment deleted..,  I was thinking charindex not patindex

Comment: Not sure why the OP is using `PATINDEX` in truth. Seems like a strings of `OR`s would be better. `[First Name] = 'John' OR [First Name] = 'A' OR... [Address2] = 'UAE'`